# Create read only undeletable file

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I tried to create file that will not be deletable and read only. (Its an exe, so maybe I need execute too.)

I tried to achieve it with this:

```
SetFileAttributes(My_File_Path,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY);
```

but it only protected against writes (it lets read it but not write to it), while against delete it's doing nothing, even though according to MSDN it's supposed to protect from deletion also:

> A file that is read-only. Applications can read the file, but cannot write to it or delete it. This attribute is not honored on directories.  For more information, see "You cannot view or change the Read-only or the System attributes of folders in Windows Server 2003, in Windows XP, or in Windows Vista

How can I prevent the file from being deleted?

- The file system is NTFS.
- It's for protection. The files are for kids' use, and I want to prevent them from deleting the file. (Or, make deleting hard as possible.)
- I am looking for a programmatic solution

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Are you writing malware? As far as writing to the file or deleting it goes, programs can trivially remove the attribute.  If a read only file is being deleted then one assumes that the program which deletes it first of all clears the read only attribute.

Comment: What file-system is on the USB drive?

Comment: The read-only protection is not a security feature. It protects against **accidental** overwrites, but doesn't do anything to fight deliberate attacks. You'll have to find another solution.

Comment: If the drive is NTFS, you may set permissions. But any administrator on other machine may override it. Encryption may help to protect the files. Bit locker may also help. They are beyond basic file attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a file is a directory change, actually, not a file change. And as noted you can't use attributes, you need full-blown NTFS Access Control Lists (ACL) for that. In particular, what you need is an Access Control Entry (ACE) that

1. Denies
2. To `Everyone`
3. The right to modify the entire directory

You may optionally prefix another ACE to the ACL with the properties

1. Allows
2. To `yourself`
3. The right to modify the entire directory

ACE's on an ACL are processed in order, so this prevents you from locking yourself out.